# How do I store a value in a Chrome extension that is deleted when I quit the browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have something in my Chrome extension that should be done only once per session.

So I think of a flag for checking if certain tasks are done, this flag should persist even when the content scripts are executed in new tabs, but it should be cleared when I quit the browser.

How can I do this?

Comment: Browser Local storage http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: I think you meant sessionStorage. For this check window.sessionStorage. Also please don't link to w3schools, it's horribly outdated in some parts. If you need to link something, please use MDN.

Comment: @SargoDarya  According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage): "Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated, which differs from how session cookies work.". This behavior would prevent me from getting the flag value when my content scripts run in new tabs.